# Change draw order of sprites within one sknode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I need to force/specify the drawing order of all children within node A. I have `SKView.ignoresSiblingOrder = NO`. If I start setting zPosition on the sprites inside node A (inside `update:` of the scene), the drawing order would also affect globally so that the children inside node A draws on top of/behind other nodes that are not children of node A, and this messes things up. So I specifically need to adjust the drawing order of the children **within node A**. How? I can't rearrange the order of the sprite in the children array in `update:` now can I (performance hit...)?

Update: judging from the SpriteKit reference, for complex scenes we probably have no choice but to set zPosition for everything. I'll do that for now, see if it holds.

Comment: If you have found a solution which (partially) answers your question, please add it and mark it as the accepted answer.